# javascript to recognize that it is being clicked again, to reverse changes it made when initially clicked

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this bit of JavaScript that is fired when I press a button on the page. When pressed, it fires an event that runs this code and it turns styled text into html source code:

```
showHTMLmarkupCode: function(e) {
    var text = document.createTextNode($('.storyBookText').html());
    var html = $('.storyBookText').html();
    $('.storyBookText').empty();
    $('.storyBookText').append(text);
}
```

It works the first time you press the button.

So if I have text like this:

**This is bold**

When I press the button, it will show this:

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;">This is bold</span>
```

Which is what I want.

But if I press it again, to go back to the styled text, it does this:

```
&lt;span style="font-weight: bold;"&gt;This is bold&lt;/span&gt;
```

Is there a way to code it so that when it's pressed a second time, it reverts back to the styled text instead of the ugly code?

Thanks!

Modified function:

```
showSourceCode: function(e) {
    console.log('show source code clicked');
    console.log("isHTML: ", isHTML);
    if (isHTML) {
        $('.storyBookText').textContent = $('.storyBookText').innerHTML;
    } else {
        $('.storyBookText').innerHTML = $('.storyBookText').textContent;
    }
    isHTML = !isHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish the text to HTML conversion by setting the [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property of the parent to its [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```js
const $button = document.getElementById('button');
const $element = document.querySelector('.storyBookText');
let isHTML = true;

$button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (isHTML) {
    $element.textContent = $element.innerHTML;
  } else {
    $element.innerHTML = $element.textContent;
  }
  isHTML = !isHTML;
});
```

```html
<div class="storyBookText">
  <span style="font-weight: bold;">This is bold</span>
</div>

<button id="button">Change</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples!  Would I be able to replace my code and use your if else statement inside my original showHTMLmarkupCode function?

Comment: Sure you can do that. Note that you'll want to define the `isHTML` variable outside of your function, so it can keep track if you are converting from `HTML -> text` or `text -> HTML` between function calls.

Comment: Thanks so I did that and added the modified function to my original question above.  But now, when I click, it does nothing.  I added 2 console.log lines and I do see those when I click.  I also see isHTML changing from true to false when I click...so Im not sure why it's not working.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), perhaps then we could get to the bottom of this together.